# Loop vlcj live streaming over http from local file

Tags: java, vlc, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, vlcj

I'm trying to play a local file as live stream.

This is how

```
mrl = "movie.ts";
mediaPlayer.setRepeat(true);
mediaPlayer
    .playMedia(
                mrl,
                ":sout=#duplicate{dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=127.0.0.1:5555/}",
                "--repeat", ":sout-keep", "--loop");
```

The streaming is successfull but does not loop. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the live stream actually ends? You need to add a MediaPlayerEventListener add see if you get the "finished" event. If you never get the finished event, it can't know to loop.

Comment: I am getting the "finished" event. Once the video is finished, a new VLC window opens up which is playing the video instead of streaming it.

Comment: If a new VLC window opens up it means your own window handle has become invalid somehow. This stuff does work, so I think you need to post a self-contained runnable test-case that demonstrates your problem before anyone can help you.

Comment: String media = "streams/Turbo.mp4";

String options = ":sout=#duplicate{dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=127.0.0.1:5555/vldms/}";

String mrl = new FileMrl().file(media).value();

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayerFactory().newHeadlessMediaPlayer();

mediaPlayer.addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEndEvent());//just prints finished

mediaPlayer.setRepeat(true);

mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl, options);

try {

 Thread.currentThread().join();

} catch (InterruptedException e) {

 e.printStackTrace();

}

Comment: You should edit your question rather than posting code in a comment. What you posted does not look like a standalone test-case either.